# If $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{5^n.a_n}$ converges and $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{(-5)^n.a_n}$ diverges, choose the correct answer

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I found an interesting problem, which I'm unable to solve completely:

> If $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{5^n.a_n}$ converges and
> $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{(-5)^n.a_n}$ diverges, choose the correct
> answer:
>
> - $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{5^n.a_n}$ converges: A) absolutely, B) conditionally
> - $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{4^n.a_n}$ converges: A) absolutely, B) conditionally, C) does not
> - $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{7^n.a_n}$ converges: A) absolutely, B) conditionally, C) does not

Now, $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{|(-5)^n.a_n|}=\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{|5^n.a_n|}$. If $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{5^n.a_n}$ converges absolutely, then $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{(-5)^n.a_n}$ would also converge absolutely, but the task says it diverges. Therefore, $\sum\limits_{0}^{\infty}{5^n.a_n}$ *converges conditionally (B)*.
But what about the second and third bullet points? I have no idea what to do there.

Comment: Is $a_n\geq 0$?

Comment: If it is the first bullet point is obvious

Comment: @Mikasa Infortunately, what I've written is the only information available.

Comment: @blamethelag I can't think of a way to use the first bullet point to solve the other two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key result is Theorem 1 of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3433667/80734), the relevant part reads:

> **Theorem 1.** Any power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n $ that converges at one $x_0$ where $|x_0|=\rho>0$, converges absolutely and locally uniformly  on the set $|x|<\rho $.

From this, we see immediately that it converges absolutely at $x=4$, And it cannot converge at $x=7$ (as this would imply the absolute convergence at $x=5$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It turns out the answer is simple.